# Extracting every nth element of vector of lists

Tags: r, list, vector

I have the following ids.

```
ids <- c('a-000', 'b-001', 'c-002')
```

I want to extract the numeric part of them (001, 002, 003).
I tried this :

```
(str_split(ids, '-', n=2))[2]
```

returns the following :

```
[[1]]
[1] "b"   "001"
```

I don't want the second element of the list. I want the second element of all elements in the vector. I know this is definitely a basic question, but how do I resolve the syntax conflict? Going through lambda function ?

Comment: Would this `sub('.*-', '', ids)` suffice?

Answer (score 2):

The function is also available in base R.

```
sapply(strsplit(ids, "-"), `[`, 2)
# [1] "000" "001" "002"
```

You can also try `gsub` and `substring`.

```
gsub("\\D+", "", ids)
# [1] "000" "001" "002"
substring(ids, 3)
# [1] "000" "001" "002"
```

Comment: Looks good. What's the point of the `[` character here ?

Comment: @LouisGRIMALDI It is the bracket function, type `?\`[\`` into R console to open the help page.

Answer (score 1):

To continue with your attempt, you can use `sapply` :

```
sapply(stringr::str_split(ids, '-', n=2), `[`, 2)
#[1] "000" "001" "002"
```

It is better to use `str_split_fixed` though here.

```
stringr::str_split_fixed(ids, '-', n=2)[, 2]
#[1] "000" "001" "002"
```

---

Or in base R :

```
sub('.*?-(.*)-?.*', '\\1', ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `str_remove(ids, "\\D+")`

Answer (score 1):

With base R you can remove all the characters that are not digits:

```r
ids <- c('a-000', 'b-001', 'c-002')

gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", ids)
#> [1] "000" "001" "002"
```

`[:digit:]` is regex for digit and `^` means everything that is not a digit, so you basically replace every other characters with empty string `""`.

For more information see documentation for [`gsub()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) and [regex](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) in R.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(ids, "\\D+", "")
#[1] "000" "001" "002"
```